# Certain elements of a page changes its style when opening chrome devtools

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, google-chrome-devtools, media-queries

I'm working on this static webpage. It's built with VueJS/NuxtJS, with Buefy as the as the UI library and I'm completely new to these technologies.

My problem is whenever I open chrome dev tools, the certain elements of a page changes its style on their own. I'm thinking of media query has something to do with this, but I cannot find the culprit media query though. This is happening in several parts of my webpage, but for simplicity I'll take this one example.

So this section is color red
[image]

And here is the CSS for that:

```
    .mar-awesome {
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: red;
  }
```

Then if I inspect element or open chrome dev tools, on the smallest possible window, after a few seconds it turns to black color like this:
[image]

And I'm guessing it's now referring to this CSS code(root.scss), on the body part:

```
$primary-font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
$primary-font-color: #333 !default;

html {
    line-height: 1.15px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    height: 100%;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-padding-top: 95px;

    @media (max-width: 1024px) {
        height: unset;
    }

    body {
        font-family: $primary-font-family !important;
        color: $primary-font-color;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
        height: 100%;


        @media (max-width: 1024px) {
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        main.page-content {
            padding: 1.5rem 1rem 1.5rem 1rem;
        }

        #__nuxt,
        #__layout,
        .client-view {
            height: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way here is the vue file:

```
    <template lang="pug">
   
        .mar-awesome
            .content-width.content-height-padding
                | Mar is awesome. He’s so amazing we wish we had a dozen of him.
                br
                | The problem is we don’t, and Mar will only work 90 hours a week.   
</template>
```

Can anyone please give me an idea why is this happening?

Comment: hello I found the culprit. It has nothing to do with my CSS, it's a bug in chrome developer tools. I need to reset the devtool then it worked fine now.

Comment: Does the color changes if you turn off DevTools? If you have a link to a demo, we can report a bug in DevTools to get it fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit. It has nothing to do with my CSS, it's a bug in chrome developer tools. I need to reset the devtool then it worked fine now.